# How to redraw terminal window after wall command displays message

Tags: command-line, vim

I have a script that will send `wall` notification to all open terminal sessions  when battery gets bellow certain percentage,and will continue doing so every minute until power source is plugged in.

Sometimes I work in `vim` and it's somewhat annoying to not being able to see what mode I am currently in or whether or not I've written the file. So are there any better ways than doing `:wq` and re-opening the file ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> or `:redraw!`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/various.txt.html#CTRL-L) will clear and redraw the screen:

```
                                                        CTRL-L
CTRL-L                  Clear and redraw the screen.  The redraw may happen
                        later, after processing typeahead.

                                                        :redr :redraw
:redr[aw][!]            Redraw the screen right now.  When ! is included it is
                        cleared first.
                        Useful to update the screen halfway executing a script
                        or function.  Also when halfway a mapping and
                        'lazyredraw' is set.
```